# Confusing reference/assignment behaviour in Pandas when swapping two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pass-by-reference

I recently had to swap two columns, `x` and `y` in a Pandas DataFrame.
Normally, I would do something like the following (here in numpy):

```py
x = ['A' for i in range(2)]
y = ['B' for i in range(2)]
print([x, y])
# [['A', 'A'], ['B', 'B']]

tmp = x
x = y
y = tmp
print([x, y])
# [['B', 'B'], ['A', 'A']]
```

Doing the same with columns of a DataFrame doesn't quite work

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = ['A' for i in range(2)]
df['y'] = ['B' for i in range(2)]
print(df)
#   x  y
#0  A  B
#1  A  B

tmp = df['x']
df['x'] = df['y']
df['y'] = tmp
print(df)
#   x  y
#0  B  B
#1  B  B

print(tmp)
#0    B
#1    B
#Name: x, dtype: object
```

**What's going on here?**
I guess it's something to do with pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value,
but I can't find anything more specific.

For reference, the correct way to swap columns is

```py
# Correct way
df = df.rename({'x':'y', 'y':'x'}, axis=1)
```

Packages:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)
# 0.25.0
```

Comment: tmp = df['x'] is a `pass-by-reference` so once `df['x']` is changed tmp will change, not sure what's confusing

Comment: What's confusing is that this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = ['A' for i in range(2)]
df['y'] = ['B' for i in range(2)]
print(df)
#   x  y
#0  A  B
#1  A  B

tmp = df['x'].copy()
df['x'] = df['y']
df['y'] = tmp
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   x  y
0  A  B
1  A  B
   x  y
0  B  A
1  B  A
```

But as you pointed out, `rename` is the way to go.

> When we assign a DataFrame to a new variable using =, we are not
> creating a new copy of the DataFrame. We are merely adding a new name
> to call the same object

[Full article here](https://community.dataquest.io/t/equals-vs-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-in-pandas-dataframes/514515)

Comment: Thanks. Embarrassingly, I thought I had tried out `tmp = df['x'].copy()`, but apparently not.

Comment: Do you have a link for the quote at the end?